# How to change schema name of model at runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sails-postgresql

I'm using sails.js with auto rest activated at config. And using sails-postgresql adapter.
I need to change the default "public" schema after the user login, to another schema, ex: "user_schema".
I tried to change model.meta.schema_name, but it don't changes anything. Tried too change the datastore schema_name but does'nt work too.
At the docs of sailsjs they says, method "GET" calls .find() of model, and you can replace this at controller. So the only solution for me was replace the methods and call .find().meta({schema_name: "user_schema"}).
Have another way to change it without rewrite all methods invoking .meta({schem...?